# JPA: Custom constraint on @OneToMany field

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following scenario:

```
@Entity public class Foo {
  @Id private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo")
  @MyCustomConstraint
  private Set<Bar> bars;
}

@Entity public class Bar {
  // ...

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  Foo foo;
}
```

I have autogenerated code (i.e. can't modify it) that creates a new `Bar` and adds it to an existing `Foo` by calling `bar.setFoo(foo)`. `setFoo` makes sure the `bar` is added to `foo`'s collection too. Then the autogenerated code calls `persist(bar)`. At this point I need the custom constraint validator on `foo.bars` to be run (the newly added `bar` might violate it), but it isn't.

My questions:

1. Is this by design or am I doing something wrong?
2. What can I do to make it work?

**Edit:**

Some more information about the custom constraint - although I don't think that's particularly relevant to the question.

It's just a `javax.validation` custom constraint:

```
@javax.annotation.Constraint(validatedBy = MyCustomConstraintValidator.class)
@AllTheOtherAnnotationStuff
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {
}

public class MyCustomConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyCustomConstraint, Set /*<Bar>*/ .class> {
  void initialize(MyCustomConstraint a) {}
  boolean isValid(Set /*<Bar>*/ s, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) { ... }
}
```

If I call `entityManager.persist(foo)`, the constraint is validated. If I call `entityManager.persist(bar)`, it is not, even though the bar was newly added to its `Foo`'s collection.

Comment: First of all the `mappedBy` is expecting a field name (String) instead of a class, that might be a typo.

Comment: It is, fixed. This is a recreation of the problem partially from memory.

Comment: I don't get it. How does your custom annotation look like? What should  process it?

Comment: Is this a JSR-303/Hibernate validator?

Comment: It's a javax.persistence validator, which I believe was derived from Hibernate, and yes, the JPA implementation is Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you try to persist `bar`, you don't persist its `foo` automatically. You have to explicitly specify in the `@ManyToOne` annotation that you want to cascade the persist operation or you have to persist `foo` manually.

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
Foo foo;
```

Comment: Still doesn't call the validation, and I can't figure out why. Maybe it's because on the database level, there is no change to the `Foo`? The foreign key column is in `Bar`'s table, and that's the only thing that changes when you modify `Foo`'s bar collection.

Comment: That works only for persist, if you want all operations to be propagated (eg. merge, delete), you have to use `CascadeType.ALL`.

Comment: Yes, but in my small test it didn't even work for persist. The whole system is pretty much a mess, though, and it might be something else entirely that prevents this from working. Thank you anyway.